# python Rename list of files adding it's folder name behind

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
Parent-Folder -
             Sub-Folder1 -
                         FileName.txt
                         FileName.xml
                         OtherFileName.xxx
             Sub-Folder2 -
                         FileName.txt
                         FileName.xml
                         OtherFileName.xxx
```

Expected OutPut:

```
Parent-Folder -
             Sub-Folder1 -
                         FileName_Sub-Folder1.txt
                         FileName_Sub-Folder1.xml
                         OtherFileName_Sub-Folder1.xxx
             Sub-Folder2 -
                         FileName_Sub-Folder2.txt
                         FileName_Sub-Folder2.xml
                         OtherFileName_Sub-Folder2.xxx
```

> Did already manage to have the (Sub)FolderName before the file name but that not what i need. (to be done for Python)

```
from os import walk, path, rename

for dirpath, _, files in walk(r"C:\\Test\\TestFolder"):
    for f in files:
        rename(path.join(dirpath, f), path.join(dirpath, path.split(dirpath)[-1] + '_' + f))

    import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\\Test\\TestFolder"):
    if not files:
        continue
    prefix = os.path.basename(root)
    for f in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}".format(prefix, f)))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue here is that you're actually re-naming the files twice with two slightly different loops.  If I create a folder structure like the one you show in your example, I get the following from running your code:

```
./Sub-Folder1
./Sub-Folder1/Sub-Folder1_Sub-Folder1_FileName.txt
./Sub-Folder1/Sub-Folder1_Sub-Folder1_FileName.xml
./Sub-Folder1/Sub-Folder1_Sub-Folder1_OtherFileName.xxx
./Sub-Folder2
./Sub-Folder2/Sub-Folder2_Sub-Folder2_FileName.txt
./Sub-Folder2/Sub-Folder2_Sub-Folder2_FileName.xml
./Sub-Folder2/Sub-Folder2_Sub-Folder2_OtherFileName.xxx
```

Still, it's mostly to the point where you can get your expected output with a little modification.  One thing you need to do is split out the file name and extension from each other, and then put the prefix after the filename in your desired name.

```py
import os
file_directory = r"C:\\Test\\TestFolder"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_directory):
      if not files:
          continue
      prefix = os.path.basename(root)
      for f in files:
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}{}".format(filename, prefix, extension)))
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or above, you can simplify the rename line with an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498):

```
os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f"{filename}_{prefix}{extension}"))
```

Using this code on the example file structure you provided, I get an output that matches your expected output:

```
./Sub-Folder1
./Sub-Folder1/FileName_Sub-Folder1.txt
./Sub-Folder1/FileName_Sub-Folder1.xml
./Sub-Folder1/OtherFileName_Sub-Folder1.xxx
./Sub-Folder2
./Sub-Folder2/FileName_Sub-Folder2.txt
./Sub-Folder2/FileName_Sub-Folder2.xml
./Sub-Folder2/OtherFileName_Sub-Folder2.xxx
```